# How to set focus on NumericUpDown control?

Tags: wpf, xaml, controls, wpftoolkit

I am trying to set focus on NumericUpDown element from WPFs extended toolkit.
I heve following XAML

```
<Window ... 
    xmlns:extToolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit/extended"
<Grid>
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal" FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True">
        <extToolkit:NumericUpDown HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" x:Name="ItemsCount" Value="1"/>
        <TextBlock Text="XXX" Margin='10,0,0,0'/>
    </StackPanel>        
</Grid>
</Window>
```

I called `Keyboard.Focus(ItemsCount)` and `ItemsCount.Focus()` from constructor and from `Loaded` event with no success.
Control is getting focus when I press Tab, but in my case it is not acceptable.
I didn't found enything on google as well.
Is there any way to focus NumericUpDown?

P.S.
Calling Focus() works for `TextBox` so it's must be control specific issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it is not set to be focusable, have you checked the value of `Focusable`?

Comment: I checked and `Focusable` property returns false.

Comment: I set property to `true` and called `Focus` on `Loaded` event and it works. Note that setting to `true` on cosntructor didn't work. Thanks for answer.

Comment: Did just as i did for Textbox. Textbox works. NumericUpDown does not. :- (

Answer (score 0):

Set the `SelectAllOnGotFocus` property to `True`

Answer (score 0):

```
NumericUpDown1.Select(0, 1)
```

'Set Tabstop to 1
'Initialize NumericUpDown1 with a single numeric value (i.e. "1").