# NumericUpDown - Focus not set

Tags: wpf, focus, wpftoolkit, numericupdown

I am using NumericUpDown control (from WPFs extended toolkit Version 2.9) and I am trying to set focus on it via attached property.

My XAML

```
<xctk:DecimalUpDown FormatString="F5" 
   wbui:FocusExtension.IsFocused="{Binding Path=IsFocusedMenge, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
   Value="{Binding Path=Menge, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
/>
```

Here my FocusExtensiion.IsFocues

```
private static void IsFocusedChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var fe = (FrameworkElement)d;

    if (e.OldValue == null)
    {
        fe.GotFocus += FrameworkElement_GotFocus;
        fe.LostFocus += FrameworkElement_LostFocus;
    }

    if (!fe.IsVisible)
    {
        fe.IsVisibleChanged += new DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler(FrameworkElement_IsVisibleChanged);
    }

    if ((bool)e.NewValue)
    {
        fe.Focus(); // will be called
    }
}
```

When i set my Property IsFocusedMenge to true, then the focus will not be set. The code line fe.Focus() will be called when I set a Breakpoint there.

I found another topic here ([How to set focus on NumericUpDown control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050559/how-to-set-focus-on-numericupdown-control)), but when I set this attribute Focusable=true, I will get an StackOverFlowException when calling the fe.Focus() method.

Any ideas? Thx.

**Update**

Also tried it with adding an event to the grid, to set the focus in the View/UserControl ... but without success.

```
private void GridMenge_IsVisibleChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if ((bool)e.NewValue)
    {

      this.Menge.Focus();
    }
}
```

Focus is still not set (Property Focusable set to True/False - no changes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got some information from the official support.

This is already fixed. The fix is included in v3.1.
(You can see the discussion thread here: https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/discussions/658785)

To fix it, go in file:

**Xceed.wpf.Toolkit/NumericUpDown/Themes/Aero2.NormalColor.xaml**
*(for Windows8 and up)*

**Xceed.wpf.Toolkit/NumericUpDown/Themes/Generic.xaml**
*(for other Windows)*

In the style for "NumericUpDown"

a) Replace

```
<Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False" />
```

with

```
<Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
```

b) In the "PART_TextBox"

replace

```
IsTabStop="{TemplateBinding IsTabStop}"
```

with

```
IsTabStop="True"
```